# NextControl Focus using Enter and Previous Using Backspace in TextBox

Tags: c#, backspace

I am using the following code for goto next and previous controls in windows form

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)//Next
{
    this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)//Previous
{
    this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
}
```

The problem in

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
```

If current control is a `TextBox` and the user tries to type and delete one word using backspace, that time this will work and set the focus to the next control.

How to prevent this event when textbox have some values?
And it should work for `ComboBox` and other controls

Comment: surround it with `if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textbox.Text))`

Comment: if its one textbox means your answer is correct but the form have more number of textbox @wudzik

Comment: See my answer. updated it to work for all textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Another update, probably not as good, but works. I would recommend creating a method:

```
public void checkKey(object sender)
{
    KeyEventArgs a = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Back);
    if (sender.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if ((a.KeyCode == Keys.Back && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text)))
        {
            this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
        }
    }
}
```

And then on all the textboxes **TextChanged** events
call `checkKey(sender);`

If you need to add controls, just add it in the if condition.

The event that you are using checks if a key on the **Form** is pressed and not on the **textbox**.

Comment: I doubt it, needs some modifying to do that as well.

Comment: but how? @Luame Ludik

Comment: using the `object sender` will determine what type of control is sending the event. textbox in this case. will work anywhere in the form **including** groupboxes.

Comment: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {
                if (sender.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
                {
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
                    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)))
                    {
                        this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                    this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
            }` in this code not working(textbox and combobox are there)

Comment: Ok, made another change, probably not as fast, but it works. (tested)

Answer (score 0):

Most people use reverse tab for back in win form . but if you still want to do it by back button .

This cod will help you . and you never loss your lest char .

```
if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Back)
            {
                if(textBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0){
                this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
                }
            }
```

it my pleasure to help you . welcome for your thanks

Comment: my question is if user try to type "good" in textbox but sometimes it goes "godo" so, he try to delete using backspace, so that time no need of this event, if textbox is empty then only this event must works

Comment: i just edit my answer . now this will work only when the text box is empty

Comment: the problem in "textbox1.text", because we cant specify its textbox1 because more textbox are there @sourabh devpura

Comment: is this answer is useful . please rat this

Comment: i just post a new answer . see it and tell me is this ok or not

Answer (score 0):

ok then first create a new function

```
public TextBoxBackEvent(TextBox tb,Form form){
               if(tb.Text.Trim().Length==0){
                form.SelectNextControl(form, false, true, true, true);
}
```

now use this function in any where in your application

like

```
  TextBoxBackEvent(textbox,this);
```

and it will work exactly witch you want

Comment: "textbox" what it means in this operation. is it will check all textboxes

Comment: this is the text box object . i min you can pass any textbox in this function